# How do you make a truncated octahedron from intersecting plane equations?

Tags: math, graphing, plane

I'm trying to make an octahedron for a molecular dynamics simulation, and it must be constructed with plane equations.

Comment: Do you know how to make a cube?

Comment: I think so. The plane equations for a cube would be something like (1/2,0,0),(-1/2,0,0),(0,1/2,0),(0,-1/2,0), and (0,0,1/2),(0,0,-1/2) for a cube of unit volume.

Comment: Those "equations" look like center points of the cube's faces, is that correct? Are you looking for the center points of the octahedron's faces?